# In Microsoft Project, how do I delete a task using just the keyboard?

Tags: windows, microsoft-project-2007

As per title, can't seem to find the KB shortcut anywhere, and it's something I frequently do.

(Windows, Project 2007)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select the entire task first, instead of just being in a single cell:

- Select the entire row by using the [Shift]+[Space] shortcut.
- Press the [Delete] key to delete the row

There is a useful [cheat sheet](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Projects_2010.html) available on shortcutworld.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [keyxl.com](http://www.keyxl.com/aaacb21/349/Microsoft-Project-2007-keyboard-shortcuts.htm)

- Select the task
- press DELETE or CTRL+"minus key" on the keypad

Comment: Deletes data, not task.

Answer (score 0):

Delete entire row: Ctrl+"keypad minus key"

(as stated already, but not delete)

Note adding a task is ctrl+"keypad plus key" or just Insert